# What is known about the evaluation behavior of students?

Tags: teaching, reference-request, course-evaluation

Much information can be found about what influences student evaluations of teaching. The evaluation results of an instructor depend on gender, race, attractiveness, personality traits, bringing cookies to class, grades expected, and other such variables.

What is known the evaluation behavior of students? Is there any research about which variables influence whether a student is full of praise or critical towards their instructor?

Comment: Seems pretty close to a "shopping question" actually.

Comment: @Buffy I don’t think so. They’re asking about the state of academic research in a particular topic.

Comment: @Buffy It's not a shopping question, but it does "need more focus."

There are way too many answers to this question, so I'd say it can't be fixed.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=teaching+evaluations&btnG=

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: most of the research in that link studies the instructor but not the students.

Comment: I guess this is much harder to answer because students usually evaluate anonymously. It is however an interesting question.

Comment: @Ambicion, sure, but there's a big difference between "most" and "all."

Comment: @wimi You know what class the student is in, so you can manipulate variables relating to the class.  Those are the variables which matter.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you say "evaluation behavior of students", you are asking about students evaluating faculty? Not faculty evaluating students?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: right.

Comment: @Ambicion -- then I don't quite understand the question. In the first paragraph, you are asking for the (unconscious) biases of students. Are you asking for the *motivations* in the second paragraph, i.e., the conscious factors that affect their evaluations?